# why jvm always do gc when startup

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

My application always do gc, when startup. even if there is no request arrive.

JVM options :

```
/opt/java/bin/java -server -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m -Xss256k -XX:G1ReservePercent=10 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -XX:G1LogLevel=finest -XX:+PrintGCCause -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/data/logs/shiva-rds-nio/gc.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/data/logs/shiva-rds-nio -Djava.library.path=/opt/shiva-rds/lib -DSHIVA_RDS_HOME=/opt/shiva-rds -Dlogback.configurationFile=/opt/shiva-rds/conf/logback.xml -DLOG_HOME=/data/logs/shiva-rds-nio -jar lib/shiva-rds-proxy-2.3.1130-RELEASE.jar nio
```

gc logs:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_111-b14), built on Sep 22 2016 16:14:03 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)
Memory: 4k page, physical 65937908k(5662448k free), swap 0k(0k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:G1LogLevel=finest -XX:G1ReservePercent=10 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/data/logs/shiva-rds-nio -XX:InitialHeapSize=4294967296 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:MaxHeapSize=4294967296 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=134217728 -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCCause -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:ThreadStackSize=256 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication 
 0.022: [G1Ergonomics (Heap Sizing) expand the heap, requested expansion amount: 4294967296 bytes, attempted expansion amount: 4294967296 bytes]
2016-12-13T15:06:54.946+0800: 0.279: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0001481 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000189 seconds
2016-12-13T15:06:55.168+0800: 0.501: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002564 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000233 seconds
2016-12-13T15:06:55.173+0800: 0.506: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0000858 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000148 seconds
2016-12-13T15:06:55.302+0800: 0.635: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0003145 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000431 seconds
2016-12-13T15:06:55.388+0800: 0.721: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0001337 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000349 seconds
2016-12-13T15:06:55.460+0800: 0.793: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)
Desired survivor size 13631488 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
 0.793: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) start choosing CSet, _pending_cards: 0, predicted base time: 10.00 ms, remaining time: 90.00 ms, target pause time: 100.00 ms]
 0.793: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) add young regions to CSet, eden: 102 regions, survivors: 0 regions, predicted young region time: 3100.70 ms]
 0.793: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) finish choosing CSet, eden: 102 regions, survivors: 0 regions, old: 0 regions, predicted pause time: 3110.70 ms, target pause time: 100.00 ms]
, 0.1121020 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 108.1 ms, GC Workers: 18]
```

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: @mm759 I think when it startup, the heap is consumed low, should not need a gc

Comment: 'low' is a relative measure. Use an allocation profiler (Mission Control will do) or just call [`getThreadAllocatedBytes API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadAllocatedBytes-long:A-) to see how much an application allocates at start-up. Somewhere around 200 MB is already enough to trigger collection (G1NewSizePercent=5 by default).

Comment: @apangin thanks, that works.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the JVM source code, there is a subtle distinction between the `-Xms` and `-XX:InitialHeapSize` options.

- The first is the *minimum* heap size, implying that the JVM should never make the heap any smaller.
- The second one is the *initial* heap size, implying that the JVM could make the heap smaller.

There is also some rather convoluted logic for determining what an "reasonable" initial size should be which looks like it could override the `InitialHeapSize`.

I suspect that what happens in your case is that the JVM is using a smaller initial size than what you said (`-XX:InitialHeapSize=429496729`), and then resizing.  Presumably the GC run and the resize are happening while your application is starting.

If you (really) wanted to avoid the garbage collection during startup, I'd suggest using `-Xms` instead.  However that will cause the JVM to occupy more (virtual) memory, which is not necessarily a good thing.

---

**UPDATE** - apparently that is incorrect.

I now see that you are using `-Xms` on the command line.  I guess that means that the "reasonableness" logic must apply to that option as well.  If so, I doubt that there is anything you can do to avoid the GC.  (But I wouldn't worry about that.)

The best I can say is that the meanings of `-Xms` and `-XX:InitialHeapSize` and their respective behaviors are *not clearly specified*.

Comment: I add my startup parameters